# using java , what are the methods to find a word inside a string?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, string-matching

if i have a string str that is: `a>b`
what is the best way to find if string str has a `>` ?do i use:

`delimiter =">"`
`str.split(delimter)`

or

`str.contains(">")`

or regular expression? actually i would prefer using regular expression, how to use regular expression in this case?

thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be

```
System.out.println("a>b".matches(".*>.*"));
```

But in this case, I would just go with `contains`

Comment: I think you mean m.find(). m.matches returns true only if the **whole** string matches your regex pattern (in the case of your example, b is false).

Comment: ok, I'm correcting it. Since you just want to know if has or hasn't.

Answer (score 0):

That one's easy.  Actually, you don't need to do the whole Pattern definition mess.  You can just call matches.

```
str.matches(".*>.*");
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.indexOf()`  returns the index within the string of the first occurence of the specified character or substring

you could also use

`String.contains()` checks if the string contains a specified sequence of char values

Answer (score 0):

You could use indexOf(int ch) function (found in java.lang.String).It returns position of character in the String or -1 on failure.
example:

```
String s="a>b";
if(s.indexOf('>')!=-1) {
   System.out.println("> is in there");
}
```

Note: It searches the first occurrence of charcter or substring.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should use the regular expression here. But yet if you want to use it you may try this function.

```
private int getWordCount(String word,String source){
        int count = 0;
        {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(word);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(source);
            while(m.find()) count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

You can call if(getWordCount(">","a>b")>0) S.o.p("String contains >");

Thanks,

Mayur Shah ([www.MayurShah.in](http://www.mayurshah.in))